# What kind of tree is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

I live in Denmark, Europe and was going for a walk on a beautiful cemetary in the city. I saw this tree and would like to know what species it is.

Unfortunately i have no photos of the tree from a closer distance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely some species of [**willow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willow) tree (genus ***Salix***).

Without a better photo it will be difficult to ID this to species. To complicate matters, willows are very cross-compatible, and numerous hybrids occur, both naturally and in cultivation.

Since it appears your picture is from a garden or park, a fair guess would be the common ornamental tree:

**Weeping willow** (commonly [*Salix × sepulcralis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_sepulcralis_group))

[image] [image]

- hybrid of Peking willow ([*Salix babylonica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_babylonica)) from China and white willow ([*Salix alba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_alba)) from Europe

Comment: It is not a willow, because the bark is whitish (willows are dark) and the leaves of (weeping) willows are longer and smaller. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

This is a **Birch tree, Betula sp.**, probably B. pendula, a common species in Denmark that also has hanging branches. It can be identified by the white bark and the leaves, that are not as long as a willow.

[image]